# How to merge two GLKViewControllers

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller, glkit

I have two controllers using OpenGL views:

1. uses AVFoundation to acquire video frames to process + displays them
   with OpenGL ES (the video acquiring process cannot stop)
2. displays a set of points in an OpenGL ES view

At the moment when I want to switch to the second controller I do it like a semi-transparent modal popup. This is clunky and the phone has to render 2 OpenGL ES full-screen views with transparency as well.

I was thinking of adding a toolbar to switch between these 2 views (possibly 3), and using a single controller in the background. From my understanding I can have one view per controller, which means I will have to put conditionals in the delegate view, that relies on some variables connected to the buttons.

Is this the right choice? Is there any better approach?

Comment: Is the GLKView's display method being called as part of the video data delegate's invocation? Or are you dumping each frame into a CIImage and rendering whichever one exists when the GLKView's delegate is invoked?

Comment: Dumping into an image, doing a bit of processing, then sending back to view. At the moment view in controller 1 is using old OpenGL 1.1 code inside a UIView (!!!), but I can upgrade it.

Comment: If that's the case then you're probably best off forking the display logic in the GLKView's delegate call.

Comment: If you want to rewrite it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I feel like my knowledge in this area isn't solid enough to count as advice. I've done some GL work (and a lot of Core Image), and I think what you're proposing is good, but I want to leave the door open for someone to provide a better solution. :-)